# How does Google Analytic's ga.js have access to a local JS array _gaq?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

According the Google Analytic's [tutorial page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/)

I add this code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

Then, injected `ga.js` will do some magic to convert this array into a GA object.

My question is, if `_gaq` is defined as a local variable, how does `ga.js` have access to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every script on the page has access to every variable that is defined in the global scope.

This variable is "global" because it was not defined inside of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Because `_gaq` is defined globally, and any script can see it in the global scope.